Vivado VHDL NOR gate test bench u output
I am trying to write simple test bench in Vivado for a NOR gate using VHDL. I am getting a constant u in the output. What could be the cause of the issue?
This is the test bench:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity module2_test is
-- Port (
   -- );
 end module2_test;

architecture Behavioral of module2_test is
component test
Port (
    a : in std_logic;
    b : in std_logic;
    c : out std_logic
    );
    end component;
    signal a : std_logic ;
    signal b : std_logic;
    signal c : std_logic;
    
begin
uut:test Port map(
    a=>a,
    b=>b,
    c=>c
    );
    
    stimulus_process: process
    begin
    --test case 1 a = 0 b = 0
        a<='0';
        b<='0';
        wait for 10 ns;
    -- test case 2 a = 1 b = 0
        a<='1';
        b<='0';
        wait for 10 ns;
    --test case 3 a= 0 b = 1
        a<='0';
        b<='1';
        wait for 10 ns;
    --test case 4 a=1 b =1 
        a<='1';
        b<='1';
        wait for 10 ns;
    
        wait;
    end process;
end Behavioral;

This is the design file:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity module2 is
  Port (a,b: in std_logic;
  c: out std_logic );
  end module2;

architecture Behavioral of module2 is

begin

c <= a nor b ;

end Behavioral;


This is the output I am getting in the simulation:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Since you are a new user: What should I do when someone answers my question?

stiv - Hi, You posted a now-deleted "answer" saying: "Thank you those changes solved it." but answers aren't used for that. Please see this article about what to do when people answer your question. Although not mandatory, it is encouraged to upvote useful answers (when you have the points to do so) and, if your question is solved, to consider áccepting the "best" answer (using your judgement of "best") as that is how to indicate if the question has been solved. (Also see here.) See the [help] & [tour]

You need to place an instance of the module2 entity into the testbench, not the thing you named test.
Change:
component test

to:
component module2

And change:
uut:test Port map(

to:
uut: module2 Port map(

You can run the fixed code on EDA Playground and see that the c signal is now defined.

There's no connection between the actual module module2 and the test component declared in your testbench.
